# Targeting a button on a form to press, with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, forms

I know that, using Javascript, I can tell a form to submit using something like this:

```
document.forms[0].submit()
```

However, if there are a number of forms on a page, which could be in any order, how would I target the submit link in this form:

```
<form action="/services/auth/" method="post">
<div id="auth-allow-container" class="button-container">
<a class="Butt" id="auth-allow" type="submit" href="#"><span>SUBMIT</span></a>
<a class="Butt CancelButt" id="auth-disallow" href="#home"><span>CANCEL</span></a>
</div>
</form>
```

..so that it is as if the user has clicked SUBMIT?

Comment: Your FORM element does not contain any form fields. Also, you are setting the type attribute on an anchor to "submit". But the type attribute on anchors has a different function: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-type-A You should be using this: `<input type=submit>`

Comment: there are several form fields, i've just missed them out of the question. you may be right about the type attribute - however, i don't have control over the html. (it is standard authentication code for flickr by the way)

Comment: So, are you using a JS library?

Comment: no, no js library. i'm using the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method for an iPhone UIWebView, so I can't use a library http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview

Comment: Hehe, that class name is "Butt".

Answer (score 2):

You could make a function:

```
function submitFormById(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    while ( el && el.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'form') {
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    el && el.submit();
}
```

Then you use this function like so:

```
submitFormById('auth-allow');
submitFormById('auth-disallow');
```

Both will submit the form.

Comment: for forms it's more common to use a name than an id, at least for this particular problem.

Comment: unfortunately, i don't have control over the html

Comment: shouldn't id='auth-allow' call the submit?

Comment: @yopefonic No, the `submit()` method is defined for FORM elements only http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76767676

Comment: yes, it does not matter if you originate from a sibling. but you still need to call the piece of javascript. update: put the code with event listener in my answer

Comment: 1am here. wil try these solution is the morn,

Comment: @endo i wouldn't recommend getElementsByName (IE bugs)

Answer (score 1):

Give the form a name attribute.  Then you can do document.name.submit(). i.e.

```
<form name="MyForm" ....>
<input ... />
</form>
```

You would then be able to do `document.MyForm.submit()`

EDIT:

As you have said you can't change the html, solutions adding an ID are also no help.  You will have to identify which numerical form element on the page this specific one is and do docuemnt.forms[x].submit() where x is the index of this form.

Comment: sorry, i can't change the html

Comment: Current best practices suggest you should avoid using name to access html elements. Use Šime Vidas answer.

Comment: using the name is considerably more common in my experience (as a professional web dev) when specifically addressing the problem of submitting a form in js.

Answer (score 1):

put in the link:

```
onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.submit();"
```

this is a bit fragile if you change the dom structure but it is a generic link for this kind of form

**update:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("auth-allow").addEventListener("click", submithAuthForm, false);
}, false);

function submithAuthForm(){
    document.getElementById('auth-allow').parentNode.parentNode.submit();
}
```

Comment: Don't put JavaScript code inside HTML attributes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: @sime Yes, true, it was a simple demonstration on how local objects could be used to achieve a result. When attaching an event the element can be used to do exactly the same way.

Comment: The OP didn't say that he want to submit the form when the anchor is clicked. He asked how he could programmatically trigger the form submit.